# .NET rewrite rules on web.release.config

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, web-config-transform

We have a .NET webapp with the follwing rewrite rules for redirect:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to target domain">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="%%%Redirect Pattern%%%" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="%%%Redirect Target%%%/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am not sure what this rewrite rule is exactly doing and what does '*%%%Redirect Target%%%*' refers to. Can anyone give us some advice on this?

**Update 1:**

- Redirect Pattern => "^www.somewebname.com$"
- Redirect target => "https://www.somewebname.com"

Is this redirect only adding "https://" to the original url?

Comment: `%%%Redirect Pattern%%%` alone is meaningless in this file. Check the whole code base to see if there is another script manipulating this part.

Comment: I have found this: Redirect Pattern => "^www\.somewebname\.com$" and Redirect target => "https:// www.somewebname.com". So is this only adding "https://" to the url?

Comment: Can you post the complete code?